# fabric-ca-tools image can't be downloaded

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to run fabric-ca. I am inside fabric-samples/fabric-ca folder and trying to run start.sh, which downloads the fabric-ca-tools docker image. But, it is giving error :

> 2017-11-10 12:13:46 Cleaning up the data directory from previous run at ./data
>   
>   2017-11-10 12:13:46 Created docker-compose.yml
>   
>   2017-11-10 12:13:46 Creating docker containers ... Pulling setup (hyperledger/fabric-ca-tools:latest)...
>
> **ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-ca-tools:latest not found**

Answer (score 0):

As mention in README.md, you should run the bootstrap.sh to get these images.
If you want to do it by your self, you must pick exact image tag from docker hub and customize makeDocker.sh file. For my case, I picked tag x86_64-1.1.0 from Docker hub and customize makeDocker.sh.
Happy learning :).